# в recyclerview не отбражаются элементы

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Столкнулся с проблемой, что ресайклер вью не отображает элементы (при этом никаких вылетов приложения и подобного). При этом в LogCat'e: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Код Fragment'a:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
private ImageButton ib_addpas;
private RecyclerView rv_fams;
private LinearLayoutManager llm;
private Spinner sp_pas;
private AppDatabase db;
private FamDao fdao;
private ApiaryDao apdao;
private String pas_name;
private Apiary newap;
private List<Apiary> all;
private boolean is_pas_picked = false;

private List<String> sp_pickpas_list;
private List<Fam> fams;
private Intent i_addfam;
private TextView error;
private RVA_fam rva_fam;
private int id_pas;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    rv_fams = root.findViewById(R.id.rv_fams);
    error = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

    sp_pickpas_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    sp_pickpas_list.add("---------------");


    newap = new Apiary();
    rv_fams.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    i_addfam = new Intent(getContext(), AddFamily.class);
    ib_addpas = root.findViewById(R.id.ib_add);
    Button ib_addfam = root.findViewById(R.id.b_addfam);
    sp_pas = root.findViewById(R.id.sp_paspick);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    llm.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    rv_fams.setLayoutManager(llm);
    db = app.getInstance().getDatabase();
    fdao = db.FamDao();
    apdao = db.ApiaryDao();
    ib_addfam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    rva_fam = new RVA_fam();
    rv_fams.setAdapter(rva_fam); //присвоение адаптера вне условия

    getListPas();

    ArrayAdapter<String> sp_pas_adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sp_pickpas_list);
    sp_pas.setAdapter(sp_pas_adap);

    sp_pas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(i!=0) {
                fams = fdao.getFams(i); //данные в переменную поступают верно
                if(fams.size()!=0) {
                    rv_fams.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rva_fam.setItems(fams); //внутри условия присвоение адаптеру списка элементов
                    error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    rv_fams.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                ib_addfam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                id_pas=i;
                is_pas_picked = true;
            } else {
                rva_fam.clearItems();
                rv_fams.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ib_addfam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                is_pas_picked = false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });


    ib_addpas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (is_pas_picked){
                i_addfam.putExtra("pas_id", id_pas);
                startActivity(i_addfam);
            } else {
                CreateDialog(savedInstanceState).show();
            }
        }
    });

    ib_addfam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    return root;
}

public Dialog CreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Добавить пасеку");
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.ad_add_pas, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    EditText etName = v.findViewById(R.id.et_pasname);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    pas_name = etName.getText().toString();
                    if (pas_name.compareTo("") == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Поле не заполнено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        newap.kol_fams = 0;
                        newap.name = pas_name;
                        apdao.insert_apiary(newap);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("ОТМЕНА", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}

private void getListPas(){
    all = apdao.getAllfromApiary();
   for(int i=0; i<all.size(); i++){
       sp_pickpas_list.add(all.get(i).name + " (" + all.get(i).kol_fams + ")");
   }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
package com.example.myapiary;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapiary.DBmgmt.tables.Fam;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * TODO: document your custom view class.
 */
public class RVA_fam extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVA_fam.RVFamViewHolder> {
    private List<Fam> listfam = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RVFamViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context ctx = parent.getContext();
        int layout = R.id.rva_fam;
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") View v = li.inflate(layout, parent, false );
        RVFamViewHolder holder = new RVFamViewHolder(v);

        return holder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVFamViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(listfam.get(position));
    }

    public void setItems(List<Fam> list){
        listfam = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearItems(){
        listfam.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class RVFamViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView num;
        TextView type;
        TextView poroda;
        TextView matkayear;
        TextView date_add;

        public RVFamViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            num = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
            type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
            poroda = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_poroda);
            matkayear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_matkayear);
            date_add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_pasdate);
        }

        public void bind(Fam f){
            num.setText((int)f.number);
            if(f.otvodok_ot!=0){
                type.setText(f.type + " от семьи №"+f.otvodok_ot);
            } else {
                type.setText(f.type);
            }

            poroda.setText((int)f.number);
            matkayear.setText((int)f.matka_year);
            date_add.setText(f.date_add);
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка элемента:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rva_fam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10sp"
    android:layout_margin="2sp"
    >


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_number"
                android:layout_width="154dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Семья №"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Семья №"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_desc2"
                android:layout_width="217dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:text="Порода:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_poroda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/s"
                android:layout_width="206dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:text="Год выпуска матки:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_matkayear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="19sp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/s2"
                android:layout_width="206dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:text="Дата установки на пасеку:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_pasdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="19sp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                android:layout_width="199dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:text="Тип семьи:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:text="*Служебное поле*" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо заранее!

UPD: изменил структуру условия + проверил на правильность получения данных из бд (данные получает верно)

Comment: У вас адаптер присваивается по условию - проверяйте как оно выполняется. Либо смотрите как дебажить в студии, либо логируйте действия и анализируйте.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, сделал присвоение адаптера вне условия, в logcat'e нет больше ошибок: `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`, однако элементы так и не отображаются

Comment: А откуда там появятся ошибки? Там есть ошибки для отображения? Я сомневаюсь. Читайте мой первый коммент до наступления просветления, особенно пункт про дебаг и логирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правь адаптер:
`public int getItemCount() { return listfam.size(); }`